# Arrange BBpress topics by created

Tags: wp-query, bbpress

The default setting in the bbpress forum topics is that the most active topic automatically gets on top (sorted by freshness). However, I wish to change this setting in descending order of topics created or by topic id. I have tried to locate the template file to make these changes but could not get. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to a plugin or your active themes functions.php

```
function my_custom_display_topic_index_query () {
  $args['orderby'] = 'date';
  $args['order']   = 'DESC';

  return $args;
}
add_filter('bbp_before_has_topics_parse_args', 'my_custom_display_topic_index_query' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also include the $args argument.  Here is an example where the sort order of topics is changed for just one forum:

```
//* Change sort order of Topics within a specified bbpress forum
function my_custom_display_topic_index_query ($args) {
  $thisforumid = bbp_get_forum_id();

  if($thisforumid == 43135) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'date';
    $args['order']   = 'ASC';
  }

  return $args;
}
add_filter('bbp_before_has_topics_parse_args', 'my_custom_display_topic_index_query '     );
```